aws ec2 extending to serve another page by nginx by terraform
I want to extend instance ec2 to get web page which is pulled from the repository and stored in the proper directory so that it is correctly served by Nginx. And I wrote terraform file.
main.tf file I made is below.
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.16"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.2.0"
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}
#vpc
resource "aws_vpc" "terraformVpc" {
  cidr_block       = "10.0.0.0/16"
  instance_tenancy = "default"

  tags = {
    Name = "vpc terraform made"
  }
}
#subnet
resource "aws_subnet" "terraformSubnet" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.terraformVpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"  
  
  tags = {
    Name = "subnet1 terraform made"
  }
}
#internet gateway
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.terraformVpc.id

  tags = {
    Name = "internetGateway terraform made"
  }
}
#route table
resource "aws_route_table" "rt" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.terraformVpc.id

  tags = {
    Name = "route table terraform made"
  }

}
#route
resource "aws_route" "default_route" {
  route_table_id            = aws_route_table.rt.id
  destination_cidr_block    = "0.0.0.0/0"
  gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
 
}
#route table association
resource "aws_route_table_association" "a" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.terraformSubnet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.rt.id
}
#security group
resource "aws_security_group" "websg" {
  name        = "websg"
  description = "terraform security group"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.terraformVpc.id

  ingress {
    description = "SSH"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
    ingress {
    description = "HTTP"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "websg"
  }

}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  ami                   = "ami-080e1f13689e07408"
  instance_type         = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id             = aws_subnet.terraformSubnet.id 
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.websg.id]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  key_name              = "ec2instance"
  user_data = templatefile("${path.module}/user_data.sh", {
    instance_name = "MyEC2Instance"
  })

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo apt-get update -y",
      "sudo apt-get install -y git npm",
      "git clone https://gitlab.com/sealy/simple-webapp.git",
      "cd simple-webapp",
      "npm install",
      "npm run build",
      "sudo mv dist/. /var/www/html/",
      "sudo systemctl restart nginx"
    ]
  }
  tags = {  
    Name = "instance terraform made"
  }
}


And user_data.sh is below.
#!/bin/bash
echo "Welcome to ${instance_name}"
# # Update the package list
sudo apt-get update -y

# # Install Nginx
sudo apt-get install nginx -y

# # Start Nginx
sudo systemctl start nginx

# # Enable Nginx to start on boot
sudo systemctl enable nginx

from aws ec2 corner, I can see instance made successfully.
I don't want basic nginx page when I connect the instance through the public IP adress.
I want https://gitlab.com/sealy/simple-webapp this build product when I go through the public IP adress. But it keeps showing the basic nginx page.
What should I edit in provisioning part (it is located in instance part) in main.tf file?

I would check the /var/log/cloud-init-output.log or /var/log/cloud-init.log for any errors. The instance booting up successfully does not mean the cloud init did what it was supposed to do.

When I command to see log , I see just like this.
modules:config, modules:final log..
does it mean it successfully ran privisioner?

Well, that's too little information to know. Also, why do you run a similar set of commands in the user data script and in the remote provisioner? It would make more sense to me to do it in the user data script.

yeah you are right. So I deleted provisioner part in maint.tf file,
I edited user_data.sh file like below.
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y git npm
git clone https://gitlab.com/sealy/simple-webapp.git
cd simple-webapp
npm install
export PORT=80
npm run start
but it still didn't work

I would try adding sudo in front of npm install and maybe even use sudo npm install -g which I think is not usually a good practice, but if you're only testing, it can probably help. You might also need sudo also with npm run start.

thanks a lot for your replies. I solved without adding sudo command. I just edited user_data   = file("user_data.sh"). And it worked!

Issue seems to be with npm run build . There is no build option available there. If you are trying to get a simple page loaded, use below 2 commands in your maint.tf instead of the simple-webapp:
echo "<html><body><p><b>Welcome to page</b></p></body></html>" >> index.html
sudo mv index.html /var/www/html/
sudo systemctl restart nginx

Edit:
Moved everything to user-data as below and it worked.
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update -y 
apt-get install -y git npm 
git clone https://gitlab.com/sealy/simple-webapp.git 
cd simple-webapp 
npm install 
chown root .
PORT=80 npm run start


thanks for reply.
but isn't it build here in provisioner?
provisioner "remote-exec" {
inline = [
"sudo apt-get update -y",
"sudo apt-get install -y git npm",
"git clone https://gitlab.com/sealy/simple-webapp.git",
"cd simple-webapp",
"npm install",
"npm run build",
"sudo mv dist/. /var/www/html/",
"sudo systemctl restart nginx"
]
}
I think it is not working..
And I'm trying to see log about it but only "permission denied" comes out.

@Hyeri1ee Managed to make it work with user-data. Updating my above answer to include everything in user-data.

thanks a lot for your solution! chown root . may help but I solved with editing main.tf with user_data   = file("user_data.sh")! Thanks a lot
